# JavaScript forEach method not work with Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, foreach, arrow-functions

```js
const array3 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40];
const function5 = (index, element) => {return index + ": " + element};
console.log(array3.forEach(function5));
```

Why this code not work, what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.map()` as `.forEach()` will return you `undefined` always, and the result you expect can be obtained by using `map()` function:

```js
const array3 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40];
const function5 = (index, element) => {return index + ": " + element};
console.log(array3.map(function5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This returns a new array.

```js
const
    array3 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40],
    function5 = (index, element) => index + ": " + element;

console.log(array3.map(function5));
```